# Adding numbers to arraylist from text file java

Tags: java, text, arraylist, coordinates, point

My data file looks like this( 1st column-x; 2nd-y; 3rd-type):

```
    46    80     2
    95    75     2
    78    85     2
    59    54     1
    81    52     2
    57    78     1
    72    46     2
```

I am trying to save x and y coordinates in two different arraylists of points depending on their type.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class program {

    public static void main(String []args)  {
        ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();
        ArrayList zeros = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line = null;
        String file = "hepatitis_data1.txt";
        BufferedReader reader;
        try  {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                String tmp[] = line.split(" +");

                System.out.println(line);
                for (String s:tmp) {
                    s = s.trim();
                    if(s.length() > 0)  {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                    int r = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim());
                    int g = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2].trim());
                    if (tmp[3].equals("1"))  {
                        knots.add(new Point(r,g));
                    }
                    else if(tmp[3].equals("2"))  {
                        zeros.add(new Point(r,g));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int total = knots.size() + zeros.size();
        System.out.println("knot size" + knots.size());
        System.out.println("zero size" + zeros.size());
        System.out.println("total size" + total);

    }   
}
```

It doesn't show any error, but its not doing the right thing either. Total value should be 83 as I have 83 pairs of x-y coordinates, but total comes 240.
Any help??

Comment: are you sure about that? have you debuged and looked what's in the list?

Comment: Yeah i tried printing everything but couldn't find the error. And there is nothing in list, I forgot to delete that.

Comment: Is it tmp[3] or tmp[2] in if (tmp[3].equals("1") ?

Answer (score 1):

you are doing a `while` statement to read the file, and in it, for each line you do a `for` loop. for each line the for loop is happening 3 times(!!!!) that's exactly the problem right there. do:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class program {

    public static void main(String []args)  {
        ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();
        ArrayList zeros = new ArrayList<Point>();
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        String line = null;
        String file = "hepatitis_data1.txt";
        BufferedReader reader;
        try  {
            reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                String tmp[] = line.split(" +");

                System.out.println(line);
                String s = tmp[0];
                    s = s.trim();
                    if(s.length() > 0)  {
                    int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                    int r = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim());
                    int g = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2].trim());
                    if (tmp[3].equals("1"))  {
                        knots.add(new Point(r,g));
                    }
                    else if(tmp[3].equals("2"))  {
                        zeros.add(new Point(r,g));
                    }
            }
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)  {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int total = knots.size() + zeros.size();
        System.out.println("knot size" + knots.size());
        System.out.println("zero size" + zeros.size());
        System.out.println("total size" + total);

    }   
}
```

Comment: just had to change, tmp[0].length to tmp[1].length and it works. But didn't get why is it doing so.

Comment: @user2398101 i've edit the answer, not understanding what went wrong with the previous one... this will work

Comment: @user2398101 i'm not sure i understand but if my answer helped you please accept it

Answer (score 0):

I think below code repeats three time every lines it add data into either knots and zeros (3 times).  So you get 240 is total value;

```
for (String s:tmp) {
                s = s.trim();
                if(s.length() > 0)  {
                int i = Integer.parseInt(s.trim());
                int r = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim());
                int g = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2].trim());
                if (tmp[3].equals("1"))  {
                    knots.add(new Point(r,g));
                }
                else if(tmp[3].equals("2"))  {
                    zeros.add(new Point(r,g));
                }


          }
```

it may help

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work with the sample data you provided, as stated before it had to do with the enhanced `for` loop you were using it was running through more times than it needed increasing the size of your `ArrayLists`. My revision:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.Point;

public class program {

public static void main(String []args)  {
    ArrayList knots = new ArrayList<Point>();
    ArrayList zeros = new ArrayList<Point>();
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    String line = null;
    String file = "hepatitis_data1.txt";
    BufferedReader reader;
    try  {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
            String tmp[] = line.split(" +");

            System.out.println(line);
            int x = Integer.parseInt(tmp[1].trim());
            int y = Integer.parseInt(tmp[2].trim());
            int type = Integer.parseInt(tmp[3].trim());
            if(type == 1)
                knots.add(new Point(x,y));
            if(type == 2)
                zeros.add(new Point(x,y));
        }

    }

    catch (FileNotFoundException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e)  {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    int total = knots.size() + zeros.size();
    System.out.println("knot size " + knots.size());
    System.out.println("zero size " + zeros.size());
    System.out.println("total size " + total);
        }

    }
```

A suggestion I could make to you is to you `Scanner` instead of `BufferedReader` in this particular case. `Scanner` has the `nextInt()` method you could use to directly read the `ints` without having to parse any `Strings`